# script phase '[CP-User] Generate Specs' -- react native 0.64

Tags: javascript, swift, typescript, xcode, react-native

I am try to update the react native project, but i am getting the next error

Cycle inside FBReactNativeSpec; building could produce unreliable results. This usually can be resolved by moving the shell script phase '[CP-User] Generate Specs' so that it runs before the build phase that depends on its outputs.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'FBReactNativeSpec' has link command with output '/Users/test/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/taaaa-ejybfsygrxmpyrfwevuwhwcaaeri/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.framework/FBReactNativeSpec'
○ Target 'FBReactNativeSpec' has compile command with input '/Users/test/Desktop/taaaa/Pods/Target Support Files/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-dummy.m'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'FBReactNativeSpec': script phase “[CP-User] Generate Specs”
○ Target 'FBReactNativeSpec' has copy command from '/Users/test/Desktop/taaaa/Libraries/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h' to '/Users/test/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/taaaa-ejybfsygrxmpyrfwevuwhwcaaeri/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.framework/Headers/FBReactNativeSpec.h'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'FBReactNativeSpec': script phase “[CP-User] Generate Specs”

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. If someone has the problem, you should do the next

The podfile should keep like this

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'taaaa' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

  # Pods for taaaa
  options={}
  # The prefix to react-native
  prefix = options[:path] ||= "./node_modules/react-native"

  # Include Fabric dependencies
  fabric_enabled = options[:fabric_enabled] ||= false

  # Include DevSupport dependency
  production = options[:production] ||= false

  # Include Hermes dependencies
  hermes_enabled = options[:hermes_enabled] ||= false

  # The Pods which should be included in all projects
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "#{prefix}/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "#{prefix}/React/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "#{prefix}/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "#{prefix}/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => "#{prefix}/"
  pod 'React-Core', :path => "#{prefix}/"
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => "#{prefix}/React/CoreModules"
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => "#{prefix}/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS"
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => "#{prefix}/Libraries/NativeAnimation"
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => "#{prefix}/Libraries/Blob"
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => "#{prefix}/Libraries/Image"
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => "#{prefix}/Libraries/LinkingIOS"
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => "#{prefix}/Libraries/Network"
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => "#{prefix}/Libraries/Settings"
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => "#{prefix}/Libraries/Text"
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => "#{prefix}/Libraries/Vibration"
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => "#{prefix}/"

  unless production
    pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => "#{prefix}/"
  end

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => "#{prefix}/ReactCommon/cxxreact"
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => "#{prefix}/ReactCommon/jsi"
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => "#{prefix}/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor"
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => "#{prefix}/ReactCommon/jsinspector"
  pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "#{prefix}/ReactCommon/callinvoker"
  pod 'React-runtimeexecutor', :path => "#{prefix}/ReactCommon/runtimeexecutor"
  pod 'React-perflogger', :path => "#{prefix}/ReactCommon/reactperflogger"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "#{prefix}/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => "#{prefix}/ReactCommon/yoga", :modular_headers => true

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "#{prefix}/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
  pod 'glog', :podspec => "#{prefix}/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
  pod 'RCT-Folly', :podspec => "#{prefix}/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec"

  
  #Core
  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => './node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'
  pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => './node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'
  
  pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => './node_modules/react-native-device-info'
  pod 'RNFS', :path => './node_modules/react-native-fs'
  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => './node_modules/react-native-permissions'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => './node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Camera/Permission-Camera.podspec'
  
  pod 'react-native-webview', :path => './node_modules/react-native-webview'
  # Adjust

  pod 'react-native-adjust', :path => './node_modules/react-native-adjust'
  
  if fabric_enabled
    pod 'React-Fabric', :path => "#{prefix}/ReactCommon"
    pod 'React-graphics', :path => "#{prefix}/ReactCommon/react/renderer/graphics"
    pod 'React-jsi/Fabric', :path => "#{prefix}/ReactCommon/jsi"
    pod 'React-RCTFabric', :path => "#{prefix}/React"
    pod 'RCT-Folly/Fabric', :podspec => "#{prefix}/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec"
  end

  if hermes_enabled
    pod 'React-Core/Hermes', :path => "#{prefix}/"
    pod 'hermes-engine', '~> 0.7.2'
    pod 'libevent', '~> 2.1.12'
  end

  target 'taaaaTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'taaaaUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end


def use_flipper!(versions = {}, configurations: ['Debug'])
  versions['Flipper'] ||= '~> 0.75.1'
  versions['Flipper-DoubleConversion'] ||= '1.1.7'
  versions['Flipper-Folly'] ||= '~> 2.5.3'
  versions['Flipper-Glog'] ||= '0.3.6'
  versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'] ||= '~> 0.0.4'
  versions['Flipper-RSocket'] ||= '~> 1.3'
  pod 'FlipperKit', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  # List all transitive dependencies for FlipperKit pods
  # to avoid them being linked in Release builds
  pod 'Flipper', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'Flipper-DoubleConversion', versions['Flipper-DoubleConversion'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'Flipper-Folly', versions['Flipper-Folly'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'Flipper-Glog', versions['Flipper-Glog'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'Flipper-PeerTalk', versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'Flipper-RSocket', versions['Flipper-RSocket'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/Core', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/CppBridge', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBDefines', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
end

def has_pod(installer, name)
  installer.pods_project.pod_group(name) != nil
end

# Post Install processing for Flipper
def flipper_post_install(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'YogaKit'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
      end
    end
  end
end

def exclude_architectures(installer)
  projects = installer.aggregate_targets
    .map{ |t| t.user_project }
    .uniq{ |p| p.path }
    .push(installer.pods_project)

  arm_value = `/usr/sbin/sysctl -n hw.optional.arm64 2>&1`.to_i

  # Hermes does not support `i386` architecture
  excluded_archs_default = has_pod(installer, 'hermes-engine') ? "i386" : ""

  projects.each do |project|
    project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if arm_value == 1 then
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = excluded_archs_default
      else
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64 " + excluded_archs_default
      end
    end

    project.save()
  end
end

def react_native_post_install(installer)
  pods_prefix = File.dirname(installer.pods_project.path)

  if has_pod(installer, 'Flipper')
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end

  ## Fix for RTC-Folly on iOS 14.5 - makes Hermes work again
  find_and_replace(
    "#{pods_prefix}/RCT-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
    'atomic_notify_one(state)',
    'folly::atomic_notify_one(state)'
  )

  find_and_replace(
    "#{pods_prefix}Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
    'atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)',
    'folly::atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)'
  )

  ## Exclude `i386` from valid architectures when building with Hermes on iOS
  exclude_architectures(installer)
end

def use_react_native_codegen!(spec, options={})
  return if ENV['DISABLE_CODEGEN'] == '1'

  # The path to react-native (e.g. react_native_path)
  prefix = options[:path] ||= File.join(__dir__, "..")

  # The path to JavaScript files
  srcs_dir = options[:srcs_dir] ||= File.join(prefix, "Libraries")

  # Library name (e.g. FBReactNativeSpec)
  codegen_modules_library_name = spec.name
  codegen_modules_output_dir = options[:codegen_modules_output_dir] ||= File.join(prefix, "React/#{codegen_modules_library_name}/#{codegen_modules_library_name}")

  # Run the codegen as part of the Xcode build pipeline.
  env_vars = "SRCS_DIR=#{srcs_dir}"
  env_vars += " CODEGEN_MODULES_OUTPUT_DIR=#{codegen_modules_output_dir}"

  # Since the generated files are not guaranteed to exist when CocoaPods is run, we need to create
  # empty files to ensure the references are included in the resulting Pods Xcode project.
  mkdir_command = "mkdir -p #{codegen_modules_output_dir}"
  generated_filenames = [ "#{codegen_modules_library_name}.h", "#{codegen_modules_library_name}-generated.mm" ]
  generated_files = generated_filenames.map { |filename| File.join(codegen_modules_output_dir, filename) }

  if ENV['USE_FABRIC'] == '1'
    # We use a different library name for components, as well as an additional set of files.
    # Eventually, we want these to be part of the same library as #{codegen_modules_library_name} above.
    codegen_components_library_name = "rncore"
    codegen_components_output_dir = File.join(prefix, "ReactCommon/react/renderer/components/#{codegen_components_library_name}")
    env_vars += " CODEGEN_COMPONENTS_OUTPUT_DIR=#{codegen_components_output_dir}"
    mkdir_command += " #{codegen_components_output_dir}"
    components_generated_filenames = [
      "ComponentDescriptors.h",
      "EventEmitters.cpp",
      "EventEmitters.h",
      "Props.cpp",
      "Props.h",
      "RCTComponentViewHelpers.h",
      "ShadowNodes.cpp",
      "ShadowNodes.h"
    ]
    generated_files = generated_files.concat(components_generated_filenames.map { |filename| File.join(codegen_components_output_dir, filename) })
  end

  spec.script_phase = {
    :name => 'Generate Specs',
    :input_files => [srcs_dir],
    :output_files => ["$(DERIVED_FILE_DIR)/codegen-#{codegen_modules_library_name}.log"].concat(generated_files),
    :script => "set -o pipefail\n\nbash -l -c '#{env_vars} CODEGEN_MODULES_LIBRARY_NAME=#{codegen_modules_library_name} #{File.join(__dir__, "generate-specs.sh")}' 2>&1 | tee \"${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}\"",
    :execution_position => :before_compile,
    :show_env_vars_in_log => true
  }

  spec.prepare_command = "#{mkdir_command} && touch #{generated_files.reduce() { |str, file| str + " " + file }}"
end

# Local method for the Xcode 12.5 fix
def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
    text = File.read(name)
    replace = text.gsub(findstr, replacestr)
    replaced = text.index(replacestr)
    next if !replaced.nil? || text == replace

    puts "Patching #{name}"
    File.open(name, 'w') { |file| file.puts replace }
    $stdout.flush
  end
  Dir["#{dir}*/"].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```

Also  you should include all node modules in the project

[image: structure]

The package json is

```
{
  "name": "Dummy",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.1.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-fetch-polyfill": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.4",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.4",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.0.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.6.5",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.14.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.14.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Also it is neccesary to do the next

> Click on the Pods project on the left sidebar Go under Build Phases
> Make sure [CP-User] Generate Specs is before Headers

[FBReactNativeSpec](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31034)

Comment: use_react_native_codegen is defined but not called from anywhere in Podfile. From where should it be called?